Penimiut of Gevura is "Rechovot" - what's the explanation?
I've seen an idea from the Besht several times, e.g. in Keter Shem Tov 1:62:

וז"ש אם תשקור. וכל הבארות אשר חפרו בימי אברהם שהם צנור החסד ואהבה
סתמום במות אברהם וישב יצחק ויחפור באר וצנור היראה כמדתו ע"כ ויריבו
לאמר לנו המים פי' אנחנו רוצים לעבוד ה' ע"י מדת אהבה כי יש יראה חצוניות
ג"כ. ע"כ ויחפור באר אחרת ירא' פנימית ונק' רחובות כי הרחיב ה' לנו
ופנימיות היראה נק' רחובות והבן. וכאשר נודע לבעלי בינה לעשות יחוד גם
בספורי דברים עם חבירו ולהסי' העצבות יפקח באיזה עסק והוא ג"כ יחוד כו'
ע"ש על דרך הני תרי בדחי שהיו מייחדין ומעלין העולמות בכל עניני עה"ז:
All the wells that were dug in the days of Abraham, which are conduits
of kindness and love, were stopped up after Abraham’s death. Isaac
then re-dug a well, representing the conduit of awe, in accordance
with his attribute. This is why it says, "And they quarreled over it,
saying, 'The water is ours.'" The meaning is: "We want to serve God
through the attribute of love," because there also exists an external
form of awe. Therefore, Isaac dug another well, representing inner
awe, which is called Rechovot ("spaciousness"). For through this, "God
has made room for us." Inner awe is called Rechovot. Reflect on this.
As is known to those with understanding, one can create unity even
through speaking with a friend, or through diverting sadness by
engaging in a certain task. This, too, constitutes unity, as mentioned
there, in reference to the two jesters (anei trei bedichai), who
created unity and elevated worlds through all worldly matters.

Clearly, I am not a person of understanding, but we have had 300 years since then to come up with an explanation, so perhaps it's ok for me to ask:
What is the explanation? This Toldot Yaakov piece offers a mashal, but I would still appreciate a deeper and more intuitive understanding of what is "Rechovot", and what is the point that the Besht is trying to make here?

@Sholom that's not my understanding of that source. It seems davka for Gevura/Yira. Also, אבל אם אין לו יראה בפנימיות, והוא רב ורבי הוא מקליפת נגה כך שמעתי:... a bit alarming! What is it?

This is much simpler. The left aspect, יראה וגבורה manifests externally (to others) as diversity, separateness. That is the spreading out and deepening qualities manifest  via the left, whose source is from Binah. This is referred to as רחובות הנהר. For details, see the discourse, Sha'ar HaYichud v'HaEmunah of the Mitteler Rebbe and the commentary by Rabbi Hillel Paritcher near the beginning. It is also the subject  of the book by that title from Rabbi Shalom Sharabi.

@YaacovDeane do you mean Ner Mitzvah VeTorah Or? Which section? Yichud or Emunah? It's all very long, do I need to learn the whole thing to understand the answer to my question?

Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/27982/what-does-the-concept-of-rehovot-hanahar-mean

@YaacovDeane I've found it and have had a look. This seems different to what the Besht is saying. Related, yes, but not the same

It’s all saying the same teaching. The first “wells” are from the side of Chesed (Avraham). Because level of Gevurah is not as extreme, they are able to be blocked by the Chitzonim. Yitzchok is the left, the Avodah of Yirah and Gevurah, greater tzimtzum. The external effect (פעולה) is separation. This means width and depth. This is discussed in depth in the beginning of the second section from Sha’ar HaYichud v’HaEmunah. In answer to your last question, that Sefer is all one hemshech. His intro says it should be learned in order, not skipping.

@YaacovDeane why is Rechovot the penimius of Gevura? What is the "experience" of Rechovot? How do I know if I have it? How do I cultivate it? I know what is the experience of Ahava (the penimius of Chesed), but the Besht is saying that Rechovot is less known, so I would like to know it. I get the concept of spaciousness when it comes to intellectual analysis. I get that it is rooted in Binah, which is the source of Gevura. However, those technical details are not enough information for me. I had a look at those sefarim and I'm not sure they are going in the right direction for these questions

Rechovot is an effect, פעולה. The more you repeat, the broader and deeper it goes. This is discussed in the Ma’amar. But it is essentially infinite. When you say, for yourself, that you haven’t experienced this, what you are saying in terms of Chassidic nomenclature is your level of עיון is low. עיון requires repetition, time and deep reflection. Does that help to make the concept more clear for you?

@YaacovDeane I didn't say I haven't experienced it, I said I don't know how to recognise it. I still don't. If it is functionally equivalent to "עיון", then I have, to whatever degree, but how is עיון the "penimius" of Gevura? Also, shouldn't it be akin to an emotion? Why is עיון connected to Gevura? How? This is all what I mean by an intuitive understanding. Just like I can point to love, I can describe it, explain it, make sense of how it is the penimius of Chesed, I get it, I want the same with "Rechovot". Next time I speak to my Rav, I'll ask him and then return to your words

It is not Gevurah, rather Binah which is also left side. See here: https://www.sefaria.org/Sha'arei_Orah%2C_Eight_Gate%2C_Third_Sefirah.54?vhe=Shaarei_Orah,_grimoar&lang=bi as well as here: https://www.sefaria.org/Zohar%2C_Idra_Rabba.44.315?lang=bi&with=Sulam&lang2=en See also here: https://www.sefaria.org/Sha'arei_Orah%2C_Ninth_Gate%2C_Second_Sefirah.12?vhe=Shaarei_Orah,_grimoar&lang=bi

@Binyomin thanks for the sources

@Binyomin Both Binah and Gevurah are from the left. Binah pertains to the level of Mochin while Gevurah pertains to the level of Middot. The Middot are consequences of the Mochin. There is also a third aspect in this structure called “Pe’ulah” or effect.

Rabbi Manis Friedman explains it in this video, which is based on a Sicha given on Shabbat Parashat Acharei 5741, and is found in Likkutei Sichot vol. 30 p. 103FF.
The basic idea is as follows. There is Chesed, and there is Gevura. Traditionally we understand them to be opposites: Chesed is about closeness, and Gevura is about distance. When I want to bridge gaps and get close, I am engaged in Chesed, but when I want to put limits and restrictions, I am engaged in Gevura.
However, the truth is when one engages in the process of restriction, the end result is total bittul; total humility, and this, ironically, causes spaciousness within, rather than restriction, because one has risen above limitation.
One way Rabbi Friedman put it, that I really like, is that when we receive Chesed, we feel whole, complete, rich. If even more chesed were to be applied, we wouldn't be able to take it, because we are already full. Indeed, if more Chesed were thrust upon us, it would "blow our fuse", the fuse of our ego, and that would unlock our capacity, creating more space to receive more goodness than we ever thought possible.
Gevura, ultimately, is called "severity", because it is "so much good, it is severe". Unlimited, infinite Chesed.
He also explains how this is how we grow, when we start to see beyond our own limitations. People usually can't imagine themselves being in a better place, and it's that lack of imagination (this is where Binah comes in), that lack of "Rechovot", that actually prevents them from achieving that better place. I highly recommend the short talk.

Your question is a good one and is essentially asking what does the Ba'al Shem Tov mean about this particular type of well, which the Patriarch Yitzchok dug and was called Rechovot (רחבות)
So first, let's look at the specific wording of the teaching from the Ba'al Shem Tov.

וכל הבארות אשר חפרו בימי אברהם שהם צנור החסד ואהבה סתמום במות אברהם
וישב יצחק ויחפור באר וצנור היראה כמדתו ע"כ ויריבו לאמר לנו המים פי'
אנחנו רוצים לעבוד ה' ע"י מדת אהבה כי יש יראה חצוניות ג"כ. ע"כ ויחפור
באר אחרת ירא' פנימית ונק' רחובות כי הרחיב ה' לנו ופנימיות היראה נק'
רחובות והבן

And all the wells which were dug during the days of Avraham, which were an irrigation channel (of the qualities of) kindness and love חסד ואהבה, they (the Philistines, who are from the Sitra Achre) sealed with the death of Avraham.
Yitzchok returned and dug a well and irrigation channel of (the quality of) the Fear, corresponding to his constitution.
Therefore, (because the constitution of Yitzchok is the opposite of Avraham, meaning from the side of Severity גבורה) and they quarreled (meaning the Philistines quarreled) saying, the water belongs to us. (That absolute Severity has a connection to the Sitra Achre and the Philistines. They gain sustenance from it, so to speak. This is the concept of the Tzimtzum HaRishon through which Creation Ex-Nihilo occurred and the Universe of Tohu and the Sitra Achre.)
This means, we want to serve G-d through the aspect of Love, that has an external aspect of Fear too.
Therefore, (because Yitzchok, whose constitution is from the side of Gevurah, the opposite of Avraham, whose constitution is from the side of Chesed) he dug another well, Inner Fear, and called it Rechovot, because now G-d has made room for us (Bereshit 26:22). And understand that the quality of Inner Fear is called Rechovot רחבות.
To understand this on a deeper level we will turn to the teaching of Rabbi Yaacov Tzvi Yolles in Kehillat Yaacov, in connection to רחבת and רחובות.
רחבת: ראשי תיבות למפרע תוהו בהו חשך רוח. ועלייהו שרייה שדי, צבאות, אלהים-יהוה כמבואר בזוהר בראשית. וזהו סוד והארץ הנה רחבת, והארץ הוא זעיר ונוקבא כמו ויהוה הוא ובית דינו. והוא סוד יהוה-אלהים. הנה הוא ראשי תיבות ה״יסוד, נ״צח, ה״וד והוא סוד שדי צבאות והן שורים על רחבת, ר״וח ח״שך, ב״הו, ת״והו. ואנון נחש, שרף, עקרב, צמאון כמבואר בתקונים  דף קכג:ב
Rachevet (רחבת): Is the reverse acronym of Tohu (Void) ת׳הו, Vohu (Formless) ב׳הו, Choshech (Darkness) ח׳שך, Ruach (Storm Wind) ר׳וח. Upon them rule the Holy names: Shaddai, Tz'va'ot, and יהוה pronounced Elohim, like is clarified in the Zohar, parshat Bereshit. And this is the secret of, "the land is large enough for them" (Bereshit 34:21). The word, "the land"  used here means Ze'ir Anpin and Nukvah, like with the expression of the Sages, G-d and His Court. And this is the secret of G-d's name יהוה when it is pronounced Elohim.
The word, "Behold" הנה is the acronym: HaYesod, Netzach, Hod. This is the secret  of the Holy names Shaddai and Tz'va'ot. They rule over Rachevet, which is the acronym for Storm Wind, Darkness, Formlessness, Void. These correspond to Nachash, Saraph, Scorpion and Thirst (in regard to the Sitra Achra) like is clarified in the Tikkunim, page 123b.
רחובות נקראת בינה שהוא רחב נחלה בלי מצרים והפרדס כתב בסוד התפשטותה על הבנים נקראת רחובות בסוד ברחבות פלגי מים. ויש לבין רחובות גימטריא בינה פשות ומלא בינה בי׳ת, יו׳ד, נו׳ן, ה׳י וב׳ כוללים. גם רחובות עם הכולל גימטריא בינה עלמא דאתי. שהבינה נקראת כן כנודע. ומבואר בזוהר תולדות שהוא בחינת יסוד דבינה.
Rechovot is called Binah. That it is a broad inheritance without restrictions. and the Pardes (Rimonim 13:3:3) wrote that it pertains to the secret of it spreading out (meaning widely disseminating) by the offspring, which is called Rechovot pertaining to the secret of streams of water in the streets. (Mishlei 5:16)
It is necessary to understand that Rechovot (רחובות, which is gematria 622) is the gematria of Binah in its plain form combined with its Miluy when counting the 2 whole names.
בינה, בי׳ת, יו׳ד, נו׳ן, ה׳י
Also, Rechovot (gematria 622) is the gematria of Binah is the World To Come (בינה עלמא דאתי) (It is referring to the time of the resurrection of the dead.), when including the count for the whole phrase and Binah is called this, like is known. And it is clarified in the Zohar, parshat Toldot, that it (Rechovot) is the aspect of Yesod of Binah.
רחובות הנהר נקראת גם כן בינה שהוא סוד הנהר היוצא מעדן ושם הוא רחב נחלה בלי מצרים. מה שאין כן כשבא לשש קצוות דזעיר הוא מצומצם. ויש לבין רחובות הנהר גימטריא אור מתנוצץ הוא בחינת בינה כמו שכתב בערכו: עיין שם
Rechovot HaNahar (the breadth and depth of the river) Binah is thus called, because it is the secret of the River that goes forth from Eden (Bereshit 2:10). And there (in Eden) it is a broad and deep inheritance without limitations or restrictions. This is not the case when it comes into six dimensional space (of Zei'r Anpin). It is condensed (and contracted. This is the same language used in Kabbalah to describe the beginning of Creation Ex-Nihilo and the Tzimtzum HaRishon. This is the quantum transition from Absolute Infinite reality  to Finite Existence.).
And it is necessary to understand that Rechovot HaNahar, 622, when including the count for the whole phrase, (רחובות הנהר) is gematria Exploding Light (אור מתנוצץ), which is the aspect of Binah, like is written in the section about Binah, see there for details. (This is alluding to the concept referred to in contemporary Physics for the beginning of the universe (the Big Bang Theory).)

For those who would like to learn on an even greater depth including the concept of stopping up the wellsprings, see Sefer Ner Mitzvah v'Torah Ohr by the second Lubavitcher Rebbe (the Mitteler Rebbe, Rabbi Dovber, together with the commentary of Rabbi Hillel of Paritch, section Sha'ar HaYichud, chapters 25-27.

Looking forward to the continuation. This is pure gold Reb Yaacov, shkoyach

@RabbiKaii Enjoy, my friend.

Excellent answer, a real demonstration of Torah's wisdom (as well as your own). It will take me years to be on the level to understand all this, but that's fine. I plan to be learning for years to come. Shkoyach! I will accept my own answer because it works for me more intuitively, but that does not invalidate the "correctness" of this answer whatsoever

We’re all on the same path. Because you asked, it caused me to review again. And new insights are happening literally, right now. Reflecting on the root of the Philistines. See Bereshit 10:11-14 in the context of this answer. And Shemot 20:8-11 said at Shabbat day kiddush, how הארץ and כל-אשר-בם are permutations of the Shem Kadosh אהוה (Tov). The final letters of כל-אשר-בם is רע. G-d is the source of everything. The Rah pertains to the Philistines. Their origin is Petros and the Donetsk region of modern day Ukraine! It’s truly amazing.

Speaking of gevura, you are scary sometimes Yaacov. In a good way

Nothing to be afraid of my friend. I am reviewing now chapter 25 from the Sha’ar HaYichud link right now. If you check out page 127b about midway down the page, the Mitteler Rebbe is getting into the whole concept of “stopping up the wellspring and irrigation channels”. He compares it to a badly plugged drain. (כמשל בקיעת הנוד סתום ביותר כו׳) Can’t wait to review Hillel Paritcher’s comments on this.
